# Get actual size of content in template to draw irregular shaped button

Tags: wpf

I'd like to create a button that looks like a tab register glued to the left side of the window.

I came up with this first attempt:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Data="M 0,0 C 0,25 50,25 50,50 V 150 C 50,175 0,175 0,200 Z" />
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here's the button using this style:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <TextBlock Text="Content">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

But the size of this first attempt is kind of fix (dependent on the fix values I used in the `Data` property of the `Path` object.) I'd like to use the "real" size of the content of the button as measures in the `Data` property of the `Path` object instead.

I know I have to change the path markup I used to "real" objects representing my path figures, and then I guess I have to use some kind of `TemplateBinding` at the right places. But where do I get the values I have to template-bind to? The one's that tell me the actual size of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found a way.

Since there's no `ActualSize` property one can bind to and since `RenderSize` didn't work either I had to use `MultiBinding` to bind to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` at once.

And since one can only bind to `Point1` of a `BezierSegment` but not to just the property `X` of this point, I had to use a `IMultiValueConverter` with my `MultiBinding` to calculate all the points of the `BezierSegment`s to fit the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the `MultiBinding`.